# struts 2 and Jasper chart

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports, ireport, jfreechart

I am using struts 2 and wanna create chart with jasper. I have already created the datasource to pass to jasper. I have already designed the chart using ireport (just dragged the chart didnt made chart style).

Using empty datasource then I set the field name same as the property I pass, but still it's producing an empty chart. In report it works but in chart it does not. Some trick must be applied when I use the data to build a chart? Can anyone help me? Is that related with dataset in build chart?

Comment: What is the type of your datasource? Also, can you show us the chart part on jrxml?

Comment: <subDataset name="totalEffortProjectList">
  <queryString language="SQL">
   <![CDATA[]]>
  </queryString>
  <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
  <field name="effort" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
 </subDataset>

Comment: datasource is object list:

<action name="reportActiveProject" class="com.promo.accountsys.web.action.ReportAction"
   method="getActiveProject">
   <result name="success" type="jasper">
    <param name="location">/jasper/ActiveProject.jasper</param>
    <param name="dataSource">activeProjectList</param>
    <param name="format">PDF</param>
    <param name="dynamicReport">myDynamicReport</param>
    <param name="layoutManager">classic</param>
    <param name="documentName">Active_Report</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">application/download</param>
   </result>

Comment: i use irepot to create the chart by drag drop from palletechart then i create empty dataset, create field same like property, set chart data to dataset. and set the category for the barchart

Comment: this the jrxml to build chart:
<categoryDataset><dataset><incrementWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></incrementWhenExpression>  <datasetRun subDataset="totalEffortProjectList"/>
                        </dataset>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA[""]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{effort}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                    </categoryDataset>

Comment: not problem when i use the datasource to create the normal report. (just to display in it) but when i use the property that i pass to report to create chart its not working. it seems that i missing trick in pass datasource so that can  recognize as dataset for chart 

i don't know it in the action struts or in the jrxml

Comment: You can edit your post and add these comments with formatting :)

Comment: @rifopangemanan: see [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10678965/edit) link below your questions? Use that for improve your question. Read this [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if don't know how to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Your datasource should not be just a list of objects. JasperReport field needs some methods to be implemented in order to use memory efficiently. So jasper can get huge data one by one. Therefore your object class must implement

> JRDataSource

or you can simply use

> JRBeanCollectionDataSource

instead.

I personally prefer the latter option:

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html

Comment: i see and i have already searching for your recommendation. but i use the datasource its works well to show report and the chart too but how can it(property object datasource that i pass) can use to dataset in ireport. because for the first i design the report to have many chart that each chart i use different dataset (different querry)

Comment: question is. is possible i pass dataset using struts 2? (because when i pass datasource the field not identify in dataset) cuz my chart depend on dataset if not maybe as param?